# Bad magic number for central directory in databricks

Tags: python, azure, zip, databricks

The problem is that I have one zip file in my azure data lake store that I cannot process in databricks. What I am getting, is `BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory` However, I've downloaded it to my local machine and I am able to open it using the very same `zipfile.ZipFile`. My guess would be that its something with `sc.binaryFiles` but I cannot really figure out what.

```
my_zip = sc.binaryFiles(path) 
#my_zip is an rdd so I have to get a filename and the content this way...
filename = my_zip.take(1)[0][0]
contents = my_zip.take(1)[0][1]
inMemory = io.BytesIO(contents)
with zipfile.ZipFile(inMemory, "r") as zf:
  print ("zipfile is OK")

BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory
```

File begins with:
`b'PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\x07\xfd\x07w8\x05\x00@\xb5\xc2\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\xf6i\xb0#S\x0b\x04\xe2(GZ\x96q}s\xe2\x97\x84\xd4\xd3\xd6\r\xda\x0c\xd2J\x8c!Y\xf7\xde\x05\x92\xfd\x98\xa5J\'/\xdae\xbdM\xc4%!\x85p\x1e\x1d:-\x92b.\xd8\x02\x81<*\x0cA\xac6\xf3\xdd\xb6@\x92\`
So I think that's still a valid zip.

Thank you in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [`pyspark.SparkContext.addFile(path)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addFile) and [`pyspark.SparkFiles.get(filename)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkFiles) to get a zip file, then it works fine.

Here is my sample code.

```
path = 'dbfs:/mnt/<your mount name>/<your zip file name>.zip'
spark.sparkContext.addFile(path)
from pyspark import SparkFiles
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(SparkFiles.get("<your zip file name>.zip"), 'r') as zf:
  print ("zipfile is OK")
  print(zf.namelist())
```

Hope it helps.